# Word or phrase for non-linear-but-still-greater-than-linear?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am looking to replace "exponential" in the following sentence:

"The development of new technology in this field tends to follow an (exponential) trend."

In mathematics, there are many functions which are not exponential but still increase faster than linear functions. What would be a good word/phrase to represent a trend that is growing faster than a linear function and is still open to the possibility of increasing faster or slower than an exponential function?

The first word that comes to mind is non-linear, but this term also leaves open the possibility that the trend is increasing slower than a linear function, and I would like to avoid this ambiguity.

Comment: super-linear = faster than linear; sub-linear = slower than linear

Comment: Note that below certain values, exponential, quadratic, cubic, quartic, etc. functions **are** increasing more slowly than linear functions. Logarithmicly increasing functions start off growing at a faster rate than linear, but then beyond certain values are growing more slowly (and never catch up after that). Note the top image here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_growth

Comment: For technical terms, see [this table of time complexities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities).

Comment: @NickT The time complexities terms are informative and possibly helpful for people looking for other terms, but it should be noted that the term "time complexity" and the related terms are specific jargon in the field of computer science. There is a general scientific/mathematical equivalent with similar notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: @GEdgar super-linear is exactly what I thought after reading the question and before reading the comments and answers. If this were an answer, I'd upvote.

Comment: 'exponential[ly]'; [Macmillan's](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/exponential) lead definition for 'exponential' is '1 increasing or growing very fast: _exponential growth_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term for what you're asking is *superlinear*, although it may not be understood depending on your audience.

From [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/superlinear):

> **Adjective** superlinear ‎(comparative more superlinear, superlative most superlinear)
>
> 1. Above a line
> 2. *(mathematics)* Describing a function that eventually grows faster than any linear one

Merriam Webster redirects *superlinear* to *supralinear*. Unfortunately, the full definition of this word is only available in the unabridged version of MW, which is not free.

But, I did find a definition of *supralinear* at [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/supralinear):

> **Adjective** supralinear ‎(not comparable)
>
> 1. *(typography)* above the lines of normal text
> 2. *(mathematics)* greater than linear

You might be better off phrasing things a different way, like saying that the growth rate is 'accelerating', or using "more and more" or something similar.

Answer (score 12):

Perhaps you could say that "development of new technology in this field is [accelerating](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accelerate)".

In my view, "accelerating development" would mean that there was more development in 2015 that there was in 2010.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial). Linear functions are polynomial, but are the slowest growing polynomials. All polynomials (eventually) grow more slowly than exponentials.

Comment: Polynomial functions may be decreasing.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Linear and exponential functions may be decreasing. It's important when using a terms that discusses the rate of increase or decrease (like "linear", "polynomial", or "exponential") that there be another term indicating increase or decrease, such as "exponential **growth**" or "**increases** linearly over time".

Comment: There are more specific ways to indicate "polynomial" growth or decay that are more commonly used, such as "quadratic" or "cubic", which also clarifies that the growth or decay is steeper than linear, since linear functions are also polynomials.

Comment: @Todd Wilcox The Gricean Maxim of quantity means that 'All polynomials (eventually) grow more slowly ...' entails 'All polynomials (eventually) grow '. But another problem with this answer is that 'polynomially'  ('quadratically ...'haven't the extended usage that 'exponentially' (meaning just 'very and increasingly rapidly') has.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If by "extended usage" you mean to say that these words are not used very often, I agree. I can't think of a word regarding growth rates used nearly as commonly as "exponentially", which is so over-used it often refers to growth rates that are not mathematically exponential at all. "Logarithmically" is fairly popular, but after a certain point is much much slower than exponential growth.

Comment: For whatever reason, this answer isn't suitable on ELU. It would be acceptable on maths.SE for 'What is a type of increasing function increasing less steeply than an exponential' (if not too simple).  Interestingly, plain old 'is accelerating' has been most upvoted. This certainly fits to a certain extent (though it includes all increasingly increasing functions); anything more accurate is probably going to sound ridiculous (unless an approximating function is given, which would be totally off-topic).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Using "polynomial" in this way is extremely common when speaking about growth rates. I'm not sure why you think this answer isn't appropriate for ELU. Different types of growth include linear, logarithmic, logistic, exponential, and polynomial.

Comment: The asker said that the term needs to include the possibility of being exponential, which polynomial does not.

Comment: @Era There is no Google Ngram (other than a flatline) for "polynomial growth rate", "follow a polynomial trend" or "grew polynomially". While these may be used in the mathematical literature, such usages are hardly everyday and aren't going to be of value to non-specialists at the moment. The case is not like that of 'grew exponentially', where this has become idiomatic (but with a less precise meaning than that demanded in maths).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Please don't rely on ngram as anything more than a starting point. It's not as reliable or comprehensive as SE users seem to think.

Comment: @Era I've just checked in Macmillan for 'exponential'; it lists the non-maths usage as the more common. But it gives no non-maths usage for 'polynomial'. This answer would work on maths SE, not ELU SE. Please also compare upvotes for 'accelerating' (not really an answer, but more idiomatic) with those for 'polynomial'.

Answer (score 1):

You could use **Geometric** growth.  It fits in between the linear and exponential curves, and is a term that may be understood outside of mathematics or computer science.